# payara glassfish web xml filter url parsing

Tags: url, servlets, glassfish, filtering, payara

I have kind of below filter mapping my web xml. But the deployment fails. Is there an alternative ? thanks

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>TestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> <!-- this works -->

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>TestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Application/*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> <!-- this doesn't work with parsing error as below-->
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]
at org.glassfish.web.deployment.node.WebResourceCollectionNode.setElementValue(WebResourceCollectionNode.java:136)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.endElement(SaxParserHandler.java:583)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that mixing mapping by suffix and prefix, as in `/Application/*.html` isn't supported. You need to map with one of the following patterns:

- `/Application/*` (everything with `/Application` prefix will be mapped)
- `/*.html` (everything with the `html` suffix will be mapped)

If you want to mix them together, you can map by the prefix (the first option) to a proxy servlet, which would parse the URL in the request and forward it to the appropriate servlet with [ServletContext.html#getNamedDispatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getNamedDispatcher(java.lang.String)) and `forward(req, resp)`, like this for a servlet named `application-html`:

```
if (request.getRequestURI().endsWith(".html")) {
  request.getServletContext()
    .getNamedDispatcher("application-html")
    .forward(request, response)
}
```

Comment: You may mark the answer as correct or give an upvote if it helped you